# Disable toolbar in PDF Web View Element to disable Download and Print

Tags: javascript, pdf

My issue is that I have to deploy a local server (without internet), so I cannot use Google Doc Viewer in this case. All I want is to restrict the user from download or printing the document. I have tried hiding or removing the toolbar in JS but it is not working out.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to disable the toolbar somehow, but that isn't good enough to keep users from downloading or printing it anyway, and nothing you can do will be. If a person can see something, they can copy it, no matter what you try to do to stop them (and all trying will do is inconvenience legitimate users). Previous similar questions:

- [How to prevent downloading images and video files from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website)
- [disable downloading of image from a html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392467/disable-downloading-of-image-from-a-html-page)
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39462/is-it-possible-to-prevent-download-of-images-when-designing-a-website

Although those talk about images, the exact same reasoning applies to PDFs.